# flutter bloc: how create and use subtype state

Tags: flutter-bloc

I am trying to use flutter and bloc in my project but having a question regarding the state.

I saw some examples to create specific state class for events. For example

```
abstract class TimerState extends Equalable {
   final int duration;

   TimerState({required this.duration});

   @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        duration
      ];

}

class InitialTimerState extends TimerState {}

class TimerStartState extends TimerState {}

class TimerStopState extends TimerState {}
```

Now I have three fields in the base state class, such as

```
abstract class TimerState extends Equalable {
   final int duration;
   final String message;
   final bool isStop;

   TimerState({this.duration = 10, this.message = '', this.isStop = false});

   @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        duration
      ];

}

class InitialTimerState extends TimerState {
  // how to set duration and message while keep isStop not changed?
}

class TimerStartState extends TimerState {
  // how to set isStop and message while keep duration not changed?
}

class TimerStopState extends TimerState {
  // how to set isStop and message while keep duration not changed?
}
```

I expect to have bloc like

```
on<InitialTimer>((event, emit) => emit(InitialTimerState()));
on<TimerStart>((event, emit) => emit(TimerStartState()));
on<TimerStop>((event, emit) => emit(TimerStopState()));
```

The reason I would like to do this is because I would like trigger listener in BlocConsumer with different state

```
listen: (ctx, state) {
  if (state is InitialTimerState) {
    // show dialog
  }
  else if (state is TimerStartState) {
    // show snacker
  }
}
listenWhen: (previous, current) {
  return current.message != previous.message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [dart documentation for classes](https://dart.dev/language/constructors), you can use the constructor of the supper class, so when you want to change a value pass it and the others as `super.data`, I'm not really sure about the syntax but you got the idea, I think it should be something like this:

```
class TimerStates extends ..{
  //Declare variables
  final Duration duration;
  final String message;
  final bool isStop;

  //Named constructor
  TimerStates.init({
  required this.duration,
  required this.message,
  required this.isStop});

  //The rest of your code
}

class InitialTimerState extends TimerStates{
   final Duration duration;
   final String message;
   InitialTimerState({
      required this.duration,
      required this.message 
      }):super(
         duration: this.duration,
         message: this.message,
         isStop: super.isStop);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ammar, thank you for your answer. I am wondering how to use this InitialTimerState. If we create new object of that, then will the based class TimerStates also be created as a new one?

Answer (score 0):

if your TimerScreen will receive data periodically and  display changes (I mean this screen is not only to get data and for showing them once), then your state could look like this:

```
class TimerState extends Equatable {
  const TimerState({
    this.duration = 10,
    this.message = '',
    this.isTicking = false,
  });

  final int duration;
  final String message;
  final bool isTicking;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        duration,
        message,
        isTicking,
      ];

  TimerState copyWith({int? duration, String? message, bool? isTicking}) =>
      TimerState(
        duration: duration ?? this.duration,
        message: message ?? this.message,
        isTicking: isTicking ?? this.isTicking,
      );
}
```

then in bloc:

```
class TimerBloc extends Bloc<TimerEvent, TimerState> {
  TimerBloc() : super(TimerState()) {

on<TimerStart>((event, emit) => emit(state.copyWith(isTicking: true)));
on<TimerStop>((event, emit) => emit(state.copyWith(isTicking: false)));
...
}
```

as for your expectations so they are incorrect because of:

> listener is only called once for each state change (NOT including the
> initial state) unlike builder in BlocBuilder and is a void function.

so you still could use your states but you can't catch initial state in listener.